# How to close dropdown on click in mobile browser

Tags: jquery, mobile, drop-down-menu

I've googled answer too long. I've found many similar questions but have not found appropriate answer.

I have simple CSS/jQuery dropdown which don't close on click outside it in mobile browsers.

There is the troubled snippet:

```
$('html').click(function() {
    allDropDowns.hide();
    label.removeClass('down');
});
```

And there is testing version on jsFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/supervova/tc5WS/7/

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 3):

Try using `document` instead of `html`:

```
$(document).click(function() {
    allDropDowns.hide();
    label.removeClass('down');
});
```

Comment: Sorry i have not enough reputation to vote for the your response.